# Running php.exe in Windows CLI loop, very slow

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a php script that needs to run every 6 secs. Since Windows Task Scheduler only allows 1-min interval. So I wrote a task.bat file to start a loop that launch a subtask.bat (which launch the PHP script) on every 6 secs. The task scheduler launch task.bat at every 2 minute.

So the launching sequence is this:

1. Task Scheduler launch task.bat every 2 minutes
2. task.bat starts a loop that in each iteration, it launches subtask.bat, then wait for 6 second, repeat 20 times
3. subtask.bat launch the PHP script with parameters

The scheduling works fine but there is one problem: the subtask.bat takes very long time to complete when it's called by task.bat. For example, if I run subtask.bat alone, it will take 2 sec to complete. But when it's called by task.bat, it will take nearly 30 sec to complete.

I need to fix this but have no idea where to look at.

This is my task.bat file:

```
for /l %%y in (1,1,2) do (
    @echo TaskStart at 1min interval

    for /l %%x in (1, 1, 9) do (
        @echo Subtask (%%y : %%x)
        @start "" /MIN "subtask.bat"
        @ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
    )
)

exit 0
```

This is the subtask.bat

```
%PHP_PATH%\php.exe -c %PHP_INI_PATH%\php.ini  ../public/index.php --method="POST" --uri="/cron/sync" --header="Content-Type:application/json" --body="{\"offset\":\"0\",\"count\":\"1\",\"type\":\"TYPE1\"}"
exit 0
```

The PHP script is written in Slim framework, so the sub_task.bat is actually simulating a POST request to an endpoint with some parameters. The PHP script basically does the following:

1. fetch one records from MySQL,
2. make a curl call to another service
3. according to the result of 2, it may or may not update the MySQL record

UPDATE:
We need each subtask to be run in a new thread or new process so that each iteration will not be blocked by any individual subtask.

Answer (score 0):

You could do everything in one batch file, that means you include the subtask in the task.bat and call it there.

```
for /l %%y in (1,1,2) do (
    @echo TaskStart at 1min interval

    for /l %%x in (1, 1, 9) do (
        @echo Subtask (%%y : %%x)
        @call :subtask
        @ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
    )
)

exit 0

:subtask
%PHP_PATH%\php.exe -c %PHP_INI_PATH%\php.ini  ../public/index.php --method="POST" --uri="/cron/sync" --header="Content-Type:application/json" --body="{\"offset\":\"0\",\"count\":\"1\",\"type\":\"TYPE1\"}"
GOTO :eof
```

I didn't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I intended to split into multiple files to start a new process to handle 
 each the subtask (so that if one subtask is stuck, it won't stuck the whole queue). Do you mean starting separate processes is the reason slow down the subtask execution significantly?